# Cardinal Arithmetic Example Wikipedia

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Hello I am studying cardinal arithmetic, and found out that: $$\mathfrak{c}^{\aleph_0} = (2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0 \aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak{c} $$

However I found this equivalence in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum):

$$\mathfrak{c}^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_0^{\aleph_0} = n^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak{c}^{n} = \aleph_0 \mathfrak{c} = n\mathfrak{c} = \mathfrak{c}$$

where $n$ is any finite cardinal $\geq 2$.

I do not know how they got each line of those equivalences. Could somebody help, please?

Thanks

Comment: $\mathfrak{c}\le\mathfrak{c}^n\le \mathfrak{c}^{\aleph_0} = (2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak{c}$, $\mathfrak{c} =2^{\aleph_0}\le n^{\aleph_0}\le \aleph_0^{\aleph_0}\le \mathfrak{c}^{\aleph_0} =\mathfrak{c}$ and $\mathfrak{c}\le n\mathfrak{c}\le\aleph_0\mathfrak{c}\le \mathfrak{c}^2=\mathfrak{c}$.

Answer (score 2):

The approach used by tetori [in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974125/cardinal-arithmetic-example-wikipedia#comment1997998_974125) works fine:

$$\mathfrak c \le \mathfrak c^n \le \mathfrak c^{\aleph_0} = (2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak c$$

$$\mathfrak c \le n \mathfrak c \le \aleph_0 \mathfrak c \le \mathfrak c^2 = \mathfrak c$$